automatically running drizzle migrations in sveltekit on every deploy
I'm planning to use drizzle for handling persistence
I'd like to run pnpm db:migrate when the sveletkit server starts
if the migrations fail, server should not start (otherwise the app would be working against the wrong db schema)
the idea is that whenever a new PR is pushed to main, and the sveltekit app is redeployed
the app should try to apply drizzle migrations
and if it fails, the server should not start at all (or in a special status that would only display an error)
what would be the right way to handle such a scenario?
btw. I'm deploying on cloudfare using auto-adapter, I'm also willing to deploy to vercel.
the code is on github, and every push to main automatically triggers deployment of the application
